# Comparing two arrays and creating another array if the items not found

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, compare

In javascript, I simply need to compare:

```
Array2 = ['a', 'd']
```

with

```
Array1=['a','b','c','d','e'] //full subset
```

and return a new array of items which are not in Array 1. so the result should be

```
Array3 = ['b','c','e']
```

Appreciate a quick reply. Many thanks in advance

Comment: effort so far ? please post the code you tried so far ?

Comment: 1) please don't ask us to do your homework for you. your answers will be better received if you show some effort instead of just asking for free code. 2) the least amount of effort you can show is a simple google search.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combinations of filter and includes likes so:

```js
let newArray = Array1.filter(x => !Array2.includes(x));
```